# Fixing Pandas Panel Deprecation in Library for downloading multiple stock symbols

Tags: python, pandas

I am wondering if someone can help me fix a quick issue in a library I am using to download multiple stock symbols from Yahoo Finance.  Here is the error:

> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:2:
>   DeprecationWarning:  Panel is deprecated and will be removed in a
>   future version. The recommended way to represent these types of
>   3-dimensional data are with a MultiIndex on a DataFrame, via the
>   Panel.to_frame() method Alternatively, you can use the xarray package
>   http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/. Pandas provides a `.to_xarray()`
>   method to help automate this conversion.

Here is the code from the library that is causing the problem, how can I fix this?

```
def getHistoricData(symbols, **options):
''' 
get data from Yahoo finance and return pandas dataframe
Will get OHLCV data frame if sinle symbol is provided. 
If many symbols are provided, it will return a wide panel

Parameters
------------
symbols : str or list  
    Yahoo finanance symbol or a list of symbols
sDate : tuple  (optional)
    start date (y,m,d)
adjust : bool
    T/[F] adjust data based on adj_close

Returns
---------
Panel

'''

assert isinstance(symbols,(list,str)), 'Input must be a string symbol or a list of symbols'

if isinstance(symbols,str):
    return getSymbolData(symbols,**options)
else:
    data = {}
    print('Downloading data:')
    p = ProgressBar(len(symbols))
    for idx,symbol in enumerate(symbols):
        p.animate(idx+1)
        data[symbol] = getSymbolData(symbol,verbose=False,**options)

    return pd.Panel(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, and it was fixed in the latest version of the library.  Here is the updated code in case anyone has a similar issue and would like to see how this was solved.

```
def getHistoricData(symbols, delay=0.5, **options):
'''
get data from Yahoo finance and return pandas dataframe
Will get OHLCV data frame if sinle symbol is provided.
If many symbols are provided, it will return a wide panel

Parameters
------------
symbols : str or list
    Yahoo finanance symbol or a list of symbols
sDate : tuple  (optional)
    start date (y,m,d)
adjust : bool
    T/[F] adjust data based on adj_close

Returns
---------
DataFrame, multi-index

'''

assert isinstance(symbols,(list,str)), 'Input must be a string symbol or a list of symbols'

if isinstance(symbols,str):
    return getSymbolData(symbols,**options)
else:
    data = {}
    print('Downloading data:')
    p = ProgressBar(len(symbols))
    for idx,symbol in enumerate(symbols):
        p.animate(idx+1)
        data[symbol] = getSymbolData(symbol,verbose=False,**options)
        sleep(delay)

    return pd.concat(data,axis=1, names=['symbol','ohlcv'])
```